# differing numbers between YouTube Analytics API and what I see on the screen

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

So I was following the example of connecting to the YouTube Analytics API that can be found by [clicking here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/python#retrieve_top_10_videos_by_viewcount).

When I run the above code I get the 52 views, however when I go to the page directly I see these [numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZdcA.png).

Why is it that I see such a large number when I go to the page directly but in the API its much smaller? Did YouTube Analytics start collecting data after a certain date?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same question. After a lot of research, finally I found the answer. According staff from Google, the views are measured from youtube page, where they can monetize your content, this is due a lot of advertisers use youtube to host videos and use them on ads on the hope to increase the views to show the "success" of the video on their campaigns, however this is not that smart since Google controls that number to prevent exactly that, would be too easy simply embed your video on a lot of pages and expect that to be counted to views without provide Google any chance to get money (while use their bandwidth and resources) :-/